# Jquery Ajax PHP two dimensional checkbox array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have the following checkbox groups within my form:

```
<?php foreach ($group as $gid){ ?>
<div class="option">
<input type="checkbox" name="group[<?php echo $gid->id; ?>]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="group[<?php echo $gid->id; ?>]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="group[<?php echo $gid->id; ?>]" value="3" />
</div> 
<?php } ?>
```

Then I have Jquery Ajax being ran:

```
var grouparray = $('.option input[type=checkbox]:checked').serializeArray();
var options = {  
    type: 'post',
    url: cb_url+'includes/myscript.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { checkbox:grouparray }
};  
$(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
```

Since the checkboxs are grouped by the $gid->id in the php foreach loop how can I pass the array of what was selected to my php keeping them grouped properly? And how can I retrieve them in myscript.php?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `name="group[]"` in HTML, and in the PHP file get it by `$_POST['group']`, it'll be an Array with checked values

Answer (score 0):

change code like that:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="group[<?php echo $gid->id; ?>][]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="group[<?php echo $gid->id; ?>][]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="group[<?php echo $gid->id; ?>][]" value="3" />
```

Javascript:

```
var grouparray = $('.option input[type=checkbox]:checked').serialize();
var options = {  
    type: 'post',
    url: cb_url+'includes/myscript.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: grouparray 
};  
$(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
```